# Render sound and 3D model on iOS FrameMarker by Vuforia

Tags: ios, render, audio, framemaker

I'm trying to render sound and 3D model in FrameMarker .
For example, there are A1.h A2.h A3.h <------ 3D model
                       A4.wav A5.wav <------ Sound

FrameMarker ID 0,1,2 are for A1-A3.h (3D model)

How can I add sound to this code for FrameMarker ID 3,4

It is the code for render 3D model below:

```
- (void) setup3dObjects

{

    [self add3DObjectWith:A1NumVerts ofVertices:A1Verts normals:A1Normals texcoords:A1TexCoords

                     with:NUM_R_OBJECT_INDEX ofIndices:RobjectIndices usingTextureIndex:0];

    [self add3DObjectWith:A2NumVerts ofVertices:A2Verts normals:A2Normals texcoords:A2TexCoords

                     with:NUM_R_OBJECT_INDEX ofIndices:RobjectIndices usingTextureIndex:1];

    [self add3DObjectWith:A3NumVerts ofVertices:A3Verts normals:A3Normals texcoords:A3TexCoords

                     with:NUM_R_OBJECT_INDEX ofIndices:RobjectIndices usingTextureIndex:2];

}
```